# Prove $C(A^+)=C(A^T)$ and $N(A^+)=N(A^T)$

Tags: vector-spaces, pseudoinverse

> Prove $C(A^+)=C(A^T)$ and $N(A^+)=N(A^T)$

If $y\in C(A^+)$, ie., $y=A^+x$ for some $x$.

$A^+=A^+AA^+$ and $(AA^+)^T=AA^+\implies A^+=(A^+A)A^+=(A^+A)^TA^+=A^T(A^+)^TA^+$

$y=A^+x=A^T(A^+)^TA^+x=A^T\bigg[(A^+)^TA^+\bigg]x\implies y\in C(A^T)$

$\implies \boxed{C(A^+)\subset C(A^T)}$

If $y\in C(A^T)$, ie., $y=A^Tx$ for some $x$.

$A=AA^+A$ and $A^+A=(A^+A)^T\implies A=AA^+A=A(A^+A)^T=AA^T(A^+)^T$

$A^T=A^+AA^T$

$y=A^Tx=A^+AA^Tx=A^+\bigg[AA^T\bigg]x\implies y\in C(A^+)$

$\implies \boxed{C(A^T)\subset C(A^+)}$

$\implies C(A^+)=C(A^T)$

Since $N\Big((A^+)^T\Big)\perp C(A^+)$ and $C(A^+)=C(A^T)\implies N(A^+)=N(A^T)$

Is it a complete proof of the above identities ?